# Customize JSON output with HAS_MANY related output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have 2 models **Prize** and **Staff**, One staff HAS_MANY prizes

I want to export **noy only** the prize, but also embedded the prize's owner (staff) in the JSON response.

How to do it ?

```
render json: Oj.dump( Prize.where(:staff_id => nil) )
```

Sample output (But not including the staff information)

```
{
can_accept_prize_now: true,
name: "Apple MacBook Pro Retina",
sn: 3,
}
```

Expected output

```
{
can_accept_prize_now: true,
name: "Apple MacBook Pro Retina",
sn: 3,
staff_id: 80,
staff_name: "Eric"
}
```

Comment: Do we have has-to-many relation between this staff and prize ? 
like one staff can have many prizes ? 
then next question is, you want to get all attributes of prize in json response & from staff object you want the name only ?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably could add something like the following to the Prize model:

```
def serializable_hash(options={})
  hash = super
  hash['staff_id'] = staff.id
  hash['staff_name'] = staff.name
  hash
end
```

If you're using ActiveModel::Serializers, you could probably do something like the following

```
class PrizeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :can_accept_prize_now, :name, :sn, :staff_id, :staff_name

  def staff_id
    object.staff.id
  end

  def staff_name
    object.staff.name
  end
end
```